# Iterating over merged AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my application, `Parent`s have many `Child`ren. In `ParentsController#show`, I'd like for the user to be able to specify more than one parent, so I can show all of their children at once.

In my controller, given an `@array` which contains three `Parent`s with the ids 1, 2, and 3, this is what happens:

```
@array.map(&:children).reduce(&:or).map { |i| i.parent_id }.uniq
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

```
@array.map(&:children).reduce(&:or).map { |i| i.parent }.uniq
# => [#<Parent:0x00007faff17164b8>]
```

Why is only one parent returned? Is this some sort of caching in action, and if so, how can it be avoided? Is doing things this way a bad idea altogether?

Answer (score 2):

You are not forced to start from parents. What about just

```
@children = Children.where(parent: parents)
```

in this case parents is an array of `Parent` objects or an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

or

```
@children = Children.where(parent_id: parent_ids)
```

in this case parent_ids is an array of integers, ids for `Parent` model

Comment: For clarification, parent_ids is an array of parent_ids

Comment: Yes, I've gone with a similar solution for now. I was just a little dumbstruck when I saw the above behavior, and couldn't explain it to myself.